# Common Item Dialog interfaces not included in minGW?

Tags: c, winapi, com, mingw, openfiledialog

I'm writing a program for Windows 10 in C using MinGW. I have the latest version. I want to display an open file dialog, which is easy to do with GetOpenFileName. However in the documentation it says that this approach has been superseded by the Common Item Dialog, and they recommend using that approach instead which among other things uses an interface called IFileDialog and some other similarly named ones. The problem is none of these types seem to be defined anywhere. I've tried including shobjidl.h, I've tried looking inside a few header files that I thought might've had it, I've tried searching for solutions online, and I've even tried searching for the string "IFileDialog" in all the files inside my MinGW installation folder, but nothing turned up and it still won't compile due to an unknown type name.

The easy solution is to just use the old way with GetOpenFileName, but I kinda want to figure this out. Any ideas?

Comment: According to MS documentation (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog), IFileDialog is defined in `shobjidl_core.h`.  You may need to include the platform SDK and make sure you include path points to those directories.  Remember that IFileDialog is a COM object,  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/example--the-open-dialog-box for an example.  I would stick with the old way unless there is a good reason to go down the COM path.

Comment: IIRC, MinGW doesn't have an up-to-date platform SDK, which is why a search for `IFileDialog` in MinGW's files doesn't find anything. So either download the latest SDK from Microsoft, or just copy/paste the definitions for the `IFileDialog` and `IFileOpenDialog` interfaces and related GUIDs and `struct`s directly into your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using an old version of MinGW.

MinGW-w64 is much more up to date than MinGW, and there it is defined in `shobjidl.h`.

Try using the latest personal build of MinGW-w64 from http://winlibs.com/